# Search for carriage return character '\r' in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In visual studio I am able to search for carriage return character by searching for the regex `\r` like this:

[image]

---

If I do the same thing on VS Code it finds nothing:

[image]

---

**Why is it that on VSCode that does not work? How can I search for a carriage return character on VS Code?** Or how can I search for files that have the CRLF line endings? Note how on the last picture on the bottom VS-Code recognizes it has CRLF endings. How can I search for files that have those line endings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Regex Engine can't recognize carriage return in find menu](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133557)
.

> Find (in editor, also used for open editors during Find in Files) uses
> JS engine and normalized text for editor (without `\r`).
>
> So easier workaround to use `\r?\n` as "universal" approach or close
> open editors if `\r` is crucial.

So use `\r?\n`.

Also related see [Can't find the \r caracter with the new VS Code 1.9 Update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19864)
:

> VSCode prohibits by design to create inconsistent End-Of-Line
> sequences. That means it will never allow an edit to do anything
> inside the End-Of-Line sequence. The End-Of-Line sequence can be
> changed from the status bar in the bottom right (where LF or CRLF
> sits)
>
> So, if an extension, if the find widget, etc. tries to edit or
> "target" in any way in between a `\r` and a `\n` in a file with `\r\n`
> End-Of-Line sequences the edit will be adjusted and moved either to
> before the `\r\n` or after the `\r\n`.
>
> As a result, in a CRLF file, there is no `\r` without a `\n` immediately
> after it. Nothing has been lost, there is no need to distinguish the
> `\r` from the `\r\n` since nothing can be done to that character by
> itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My goal is to find \r characters. With the \r?\n solution I will be searching for LF. So maybe the answer is that it's not possible based on your answer.

Comment: Yes, I think it is not possible.  To force you into finding only the **entire** normalized EOL so that you cannot try to remove only part of it.

Comment: they are so stubborn. "prohibits ** EOF by desgin"? naiive thoughts. Now it makes very hard a simple task of "removing all CRLF"